# Triangle inequality of a metric on a quotient space of a topological vector space

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

In "Functional Analysis" by Rudin, a metric $\rho$ on the quotient space $X/N$ of a topological vector space $X$ and a closed subspace $N$ is defined as follows:  
For $x,y \in X$,
$$
\rho (\pi(x),\pi(y)) := \inf \{d(x-y,z):z\in N\},
$$
where $\pi$ is the quotient map and $d$ is an invariant metric on $X$.
The verification that it is an invariant metric on $X/N$ is omitted in this book. I cannot prove the triagle inequality of the metric. Could anyone show me how to prove it ? 
 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention a topological vector space in the title and in the tag, but this never appears in the body of the question.

Comment: @joriki, I'm sorry. X is a topological **vector** space. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u,v,w \in X$.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho(\pi(u),\pi(w))&=& \inf \{ d(u-w,z) : z \in N \}, \\
  &=& \inf \{ d((u-v)+(v-w),z) : z \in N \}, \\
  &=&    \inf \{ d((u-v)+(v-w)+z,0) : z \in N \}, \\
  &=&    \inf \{ d(((u-v)+z')+((v-w)+z''),0) : z',z'' \in N \},\\
  &\leq& \inf \{ d((u-v)+z',0)+d((v-w)+z'',0) : z',z'' \in N \},\\
  &=& \inf \{ d((u-v)+z',0): z' \in N \}+\inf \{ d((v-w)+z'',0) : z'' \in N \},\\
  &=& \inf \{ d(u-v,z'): z' \in N \}+\inf \{ d(v-w,z'') : z'' \in N \},\\
  &=& \rho(\pi(u),\pi(v)) + \rho(\pi(v),\pi(w)).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: inf A + inf B = inf (A+B). See for example Exercise 1.3.9. of _understanding analysis_ by Stephen Abbott.